# Не получается подключить библиотеку с помощью композера

Tags: php

сижу разбираюсь с композером, пытаюсь использовать чужие пакеты. Хочу для теста установить это дело https://packagist.org/packages/phroute/phroute

Создал index.php, загрузил с помощью композера данный пакет и как по инструкции написал код в index.php

```
use Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector;

$router = new RouteCollector();
$router->get('/example', function(){
    return 'test';
});
```

В итоге получаю ошибку `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector' not found in W:\domains\test\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in W:\domains\test\index.php on line 5`

Что не так делаю?

Comment: `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В начале php файла после **<?php** подключите файл автозагрузки классов

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'
```